# Configure Feign OkHttpClient to not use proxy on addresses localhost*

Tags: spring-boot, proxy, spring-cloud-feign, okhttp, feign

I'm having a problem setting the proxy usage for spring-cloud-feign, I'm using the class below to produce an OkHttpClient for Feign:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfigurationProxy {

    @Value ("$ {url.proxy_host}")
    private String HOST_PROXY;
    @Value ("$ {url.proxy_port}")
    private Integer PORT_PROXY;

    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private Proxy proxy;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init () {
        buildProxy ();
        buildOkHttpClient ();
    }

    @Bean (name = "feign")
    public Feign buildClient () {
        return Feign.builder (). client (new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient (okHttpClient)).
    }


    @Bean (name = "okhttpclient")
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient () {
        return okHttpClient;
    }

    public void buildOkHttpClient () {
        buildProxy ();
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder (). proxy (proxy) .build ();
    }

    public void buildProxy () {
        proxy = new Proxy (Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress (HOST_PROXY, PORT_PROXY));
    }

}
```

This solved for the feign clients that make calls to servers outside my network, but now I have a problem with the localhost servers, where I do not need to use the proxy, when I make the calls the feign tries to use the proxy and returns me a cone

Comment: Why not write two configs one for local flow and other for outside

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for the answer, or for the ones of you that are facing the same problem, here's the solution:

Remove the "@Configuration" annotation from your config class, and add the following bean:

```
@Bean
public Client client() {
    return new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(okHttpClient);
}
```

Also, you also need to inform the "url" param in your "@FeignClient" annotation.

```
@FeignClient(name = "my-api", configuration = FeignConfigurationProxy.class, url = "http://my-url:my-port")
```

That prevents Spring from using ribbon. If you do need to use ribbon and proxy, you need to adjust that in the bean.